# Word or phrase describes looking around trying to gain information from surroundings

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for either a word or phrase which describes the situation of being in a strange place and feeling disoriented, and you're just looking around for basic clues as to where you are, or what's there, or what kind of place it is.

Example sentence:

> Fred walked around the benches, still looking around left and right, trying to absorb what he could from the surrounding buildings and other street furniture.

Comment: Doesn't 'disoriented' sum this feeling best? And you'd be _reconnoitering_ the surroundings.

Comment: You've already used the word, but in its negative form. "Wait a minute, I need to *orientate* myself"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may **scan the environment**.

> Definition: to look at (something) carefully, usually in order to find
>   someone or something; to minutely examine the particulars or points of
>   ; scrutinize.

Answer (score 4):

"*Getting the lay of the land*", which is not usually applied to an actual physical location or territory, but rather to a social, situational, or circumstantial change of scene.  Metaphorically the person *getting* is doing the work of a pioneer or surveyor.

Answer (score 3):

scanning the vicinity
getting one's bearings

Answer (score 2):

Of course, if you are disoriented, you may **orient** yourself.

> Definition, from [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/orient): find one's position in relation to new and strange surroundings.

Comment: I added the source of your definition, and the link to the source.  A quotation should always include the source, and it is helpful to have a link, if the source is online.

Answer (score 2):

> *Fred [**did a recce**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22do%20a%20recce%22)* (about 1660 results in Google Books)
>
> [***recce***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/recce) *- informal term for reconnaissance* (OxfordDictionaries)
> [***reconnaissance***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reconnaissance) *-a preliminary survey to gain information* (Merriam-Webster)

Comment: Possibly, but this gives the feel of moving around to different places in order to look; maybe because of a broader / wider area. I'm looking for what would apply to your immediate surroundings.

Comment: @Stewart: OP's description includes *walked around the benches*.

Comment: "Did a recce" seems to be British-only slang.  In the US there's "did a recon", (which has military connotations), but it's not widespread.

Comment: The verb is *reconnoiter*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Then I guess it comes down to how far apart the benches are :)

Answer (score 2):

One may ***scout*** the surroundings.

> scout
>
> : to explore in order to gain information.
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scout)

Comment: Possibly, but this gives the feel of moving around to different places in order to look; maybe because of a broader / wider area. I'm looking for what would apply to your immediate surroundings.

Answer (score 1):

Look for *landmarks* - http://www.thefreedictionary.com/landmark

In the close environment that you describe landmark would work.

Comment: Could be, if "landmark" also includes features which are familiar to the person, not just famous in general.

Answer (score 1):

ASSESS ——implies a critical appraisal for the purpose of understanding or interpreting, or as a guide in taking action.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).